# Получение результата по выражению Linq GroupBy в lambda-exp

Tags: c#, linq

```
using MeetingCases;

List<int> ourList = new List<int> { 7, 8, 7, 5, 6, 5, 5, 7, 1, 3, 7, 3, 1, 4 };
var resultus = ourList.Skip(3).Take(4).Sum();
var yay = ourList.GroupBy(key =>
    {
        resultus += key;
        return key;
    }).Select(z => new {z.Key, resultus });
Console.WriteLine($"Result is {resultus}");
yay.ToList();

Console.WriteLine($"Result is {resultus}");
```

Не могли бы вы объяснить, почему в первом CW мы получаем результат `21`, однако после `yay.ToList();` получим `90`.

Comment: Было бы неплохо добавить, почему вы данное поведение считаете странным и какой бы вы результат ожидали и почему. Отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: Я не писал что странным считаю, я хочу разобраться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что Linq запрос выполняется не при создании, а при материализации. В данном случае в строчке `var yay = ourList.GroupBy(...)..` он создается, а в строчке `yay.ToList()` запускается его материализация, то есть выполнение.

А в процессе выполнения запроса переменная `resultus` увеличивается

```
resultus += key;
```

В данном случае при группировке это суммирование выполняется для каждого числа в списке.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", ourList));
Console.WriteLine(ourList.Sum());
```

Даст вывод

```
7,8,7,5,6,5,5,7,1,3,7,3,1,4
69
```

Получается

```
21 + 69 = 90
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: ДОбавил галочку